# How to create a table in Sql from existing table along with it partition and indexs Structure

Tags: sql, database, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a table in Schema ABC, I have to create an exact replica for that table in the schema XYZ along with its Partition and Index.

```
Create table XYZ.table1 as Select * from ABC.table2;
```

Is there any possible way of implementing this?

Answer (score 0):

It is `DBMS_METADATA` package you should look at.

In your case, to get table description (along with its partitions), you'd use

```
SELECT DBMS_METADATA.get_ddl ('TABLE', 'EMP', 'SCOTT') FROM DUAL;
```

(where `EMP` represents table name, while `SCOTT` is its owner).

---

To get its indexes, you'd use

```
SELECT DBMS_METADATA.get_ddl ('INDEX', index_name, 'SCOTT')
  FROM user_indexes
 WHERE table_name = 'EMP';
```

---

Another option might be to use **Data Pump** Export and Import utilities which allow you to export not only metadata, but tables' contents.